# PostgreSQL gist index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with two date like dateTo and dateFrom, i would like use daterange approach in queries and a gist index, but it seem doesn't work. The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id         bigeserial,
  begin_date date,
  end_date   date
);
CREATE INDEX "idx1"
  ON test
  USING gist (daterange(begin_date, end_date));
```

Then when i try to explain a query like:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE daterange(t.begin_date,t.end_date,'[]') && daterange('2015-12-30 00:00:00.0','2016-10-28 00:00:00.0','[]')
```

i get a Seq Scan.

Is this usage of gist index wrong, or is this scenario not feasible?

Comment: Why not a B-tree multicolumn index on begin_date and end_date? I think that you might get a seq scan if you have few rows. Maybe you need enough data to stress test your implementation.

Comment: You are trying to use an expression index with the wrong expression. You have `daterange(begin_date, end_date)` in the index, but you query your table with `daterange(begin_date, end_date, '[]')` (note the third parameter).

Comment: @andrei-macarie i'm using gist index because b-tree does not support range operators.

Comment: @pozs that's not true. the index will work with both.

Comment: You need to provide the explain analyze with the seqscan, and also `set enable_seqscan = 0;` and the same explain analyze.

Comment: @EvanCarroll no, it won't work. OP used `[]` in both side of `&&`. You're conveniently ignore that part in your answer & use a different query.

Comment: as stated by @pozs, aligning the index expression to that used in query solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an index on the expression `daterange(begin_date, end_date)`, but you query your table with `daterange(begin_date, end_date, '[]') && ...`. PostgreSQL won't do math instead of you. To re-phrase your problem, it is like you're indexing `(int_col + 2)` and querying `WHERE int_col + 1 > 2`. Because the two expressions are different, the index will not be used in any circumstances. But as you can see, you *can* do the math (i.e. re-phrase the formula) sometimes.

You'll either need:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON test USING gist (daterange(begin_date, end_date, '[]'));
```

Or:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON test USING gist (daterange(begin_date, end_date + 1));
```

*Note*: both of them creates a range which includes `end_date`. The latter one uses the fact that `daterange` is discrete.

And use the following predicates for each of the indexes above:

```
WHERE daterange(begin_date, end_date, '[]') && daterange(?, ?, ?)
```

Or:

```
WHERE daterange(begin_date, end_date + 1) && daterange(?, ?, ?)
```

*Note*: the third parameter of the range constructor on the **right** side of `&&` does not matter (in the context of index usage).